# How do I change rowHeight in multi line TableView Cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I change rowHeight in multi line TableView Cell?

```
  #define numberOfLines 2

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

        tableView.rowHeight = (44.0 + (numberOfLines - 1) * 19.0); // this doesn't work.

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Main Test";

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = numberOfLines;

    cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Test\nTest2";

}
```

I want detailTextLabel have 2 lines. But, I have to change cell's height also.

If I change rowHeight like above, it doesn't work.

If I change like below, it works.

But maual says that it can cause significant performance problem with table views having a

large number. So, I want to change rowHeight directly. How can I do that?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath

{

    return (44.0 + (numberOfLines - 1) * 19.0);

}
```

Comment: I will do. I didn't know what it was.

Comment: Anyway, I can't fine to accept answer yet. How can I accept answer?

Comment: [A picture is worth a thousand words](http://i.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif)...

Comment: I did that in viewDidLoad. But there was compiler error. I did something wrong. It works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't change or set the height for **row** in

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
  function.
```

if you have cells  which have variable heights then you will have to use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

---

if you have cells which have fixed height then use `rowHeight`  property of `UITableView` when you create the instance of your `UITableView`.

```
  [myTableView = UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  .....................................................
  .....................................................
  myTableView.rowHeight = (44.0 + (numberOfLines - 1) * 19.0); 
  .....................................................
```

Comment: I have cells with the same heights. They all have 3 lines.

Comment: @user698200 : use the second one